# Make a new column of the first n letters of a column, where n is the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with names and ages:

```
name:  age: 
john    2
sean    3
jack    1
peter   4
```

Depending on their age `n` I want to print the first `n` letters of their name, so for instance `sean` becomes `sea` in a new column.

I have tried this:

```
family['newcol'] = [x[:y] for x in family['name'] and for y in family['age']]
```

but it hasn't worked. Can anyone please give me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
family['newcol'] = [family.ix[x]['name'][0:family.ix[x]['age']] for x in family.index]
```